# Violation of Monotone convergence theorem for measurable sets with infinitely measured sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

While solving the question,

Q. Which are not true for a Lebesgue measure $m$ and measurable set $E_n$ with $E_{n+1}~\subseteq E_n~\forall n \in \Bbb N,$

1. $m(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n)=m(E_1)$
2. $m(\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}m(E_n)$
3. $m(E_n^C)=m(\bigcup^n_{k=1}E_k^C)$
4. $m(E_n)\geq m(E_{n+1})$

Option 1, 3, 4 are clear to me even when $m(E_j)$ is not finite due to monotonicity (any thing mislead here?), But for option 2, Monotone convergence theorem for measurable sets indicates problem with finiteness of measure. I tried to find counter examples for the violation of the theorem using sets with inifinte measure, But I couldn't justify the violation by taking $$E_n=(\Bbb R \cap\Bbb Q^c)-\{\pi,2\pi,...,n\pi~:~n \in \Bbb N\}.$$

Comment: $E_n=[n,\infty)$.

Comment: Many thanks......